# Changing the scale on a vega-lite waterfall

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I would like to scale the y-axis of a vega-lite waterfall so that the y-axis does not start at 0 and the corresponding bars in the chart are formatted correctly with the right numbers.

I was able to format a vega-lite chart to change the scale, but I am having trouble formatting the bars to the correct size.

I made the following adjustment to the original: `"scale": {"domain": [2000, 10000]`
But this changed the y-axis while keeping the bars their original size.

I get the following chart: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Smg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to clip the bar at *y = 2000*.

Try `"clip": true` along with `"scale": {"domain": [2000, 10000]}` .

(Original Vega-lite waterfall chart example is found at https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/waterfall_chart.html)

[image]

[image]